# How do I get all values present in one table, but only some from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

We have two tables with information in them about sick and vacation leave accruals. One is the overarching payroll table, and the other is a staging table that supervisors use to verify that employees have entered the sick/vacation hours for each month, or confirmed that they are taking `0` hours for that month.

The Payroll table is `PS_LEAVE_ACCRUAL`, and it has this structure (plus additional irrelevant columns):

```
EMPLID | EMPL_RCD | COMPANY | PLAN_TYPE | ACCRUAL_PROC_DT | HRS_TAKEN_UNPROC
------ | -------- | ------- | --------- | --------------- | ----------------
123456 | 0        | ABC     | 50        | 28-FEB-17       | 3
123456 | 0        | ABC     | 51        | 28-FEB-17       | 0
987654 | 0        | ABC     | 50        | 28-FEB-17       | 0
987654 | 0        | ABC     | 51        | 28-FEB-17       | 3
```

The staging table is `Y_SIC_VAC_HRS`, and it has the above structure, but with one additional column, `Y_NO_HRS_TAKEN`, which contains a `Y`/`N` value. This is used to verify that if an employee has taken `0` hours in a given month, they have confirmed it, instead of just leaving it as `0`.

We need to build a SQL statement that grabs all of the values in the `PS_LEAVE_ACCRUAL` table that have `0` for `HRS_TAKEN_UNPROC`, and join that with the `Y_SIC_VAC_HRS` table to remove any joined rows where the `HRS_TAKEN_UNPROC` is not `0`, or if it *is* `0`, the `Y_NO_HRS_TAKEN` flag is set to `Y` meaning the employee has confirmed that they are taking `0` hours for that month.

Basically, we only care about the months where the employee has *not* entered a balance for their sick/vacation hours (if the `Y_NO_HRS_TAKEN` flag is `Y`, that is equivalent to them entering a balance). We also only care about rows after an arbitrary date that is passed in as a bind `:1`.

Here is the SQL we have tried:

```
SELECT la.EMPLID  
 , la.EMPL_RCD  
 , la.COMPANY  
 , la.PLAN_TYPE  
 , la.ACCRUAL_PROC_DT  
 , la.HRS_TAKEN_UNPROC  
 , 'N'  
  FROM PS_LEAVE_ACCRUAL la LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_Y_SIC_VAC_HRS sv ON la.EMPLID = sv.EMPLID  
   AND la.EMPL_RCD = sv.EMPL_RCD  
   AND la.COMPANY = sv.COMPANY  
   AND la.PLAN_TYPE = sv.PLAN_TYPE  
   AND la.ACCRUAL_PROC_DT = sv.ACCRUAL_PROC_DT  
 WHERE (la.HRS_TAKEN_UNPROC = 0  
   AND la.PLAN_TYPE IN ('50', '51')  
   AND la.ACCRUAL_PROC_DT > :1)  
    OR ( sv.HRS_TAKEN_UNPROC = 0  
   AND sv.Y_NO_HRS_TAKEN = 'N')
```

Note that Plan Type `50` refers to Sick Hours and `51` to Vacation Hours.

There is an entry for *every* month in `PS_LEAVE_ACCRUAL`, but there might not be an entry in every month for `Y_SIC_VAC_HRS`.

Comment: OK... a couple of questions. (1) Is it true that (EMPL_ID, PLAN_TYPE, ACCRUAL_PROC_DT) is a unique key in your tables? (Then we can join on these three columns.) (2) is the Y_NO_HRS_TAKEN a non-nullable column, with values either 'Y' or 'N'?

Comment: @mathguy Yes and Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select emplid, empl_rcd, company, plan_type, accrual_proc_dt, hrs_taken_unproc,  
       'N' as y_no_hrs_taken   --  is this really needed?
from   ps_leave_accrual
where  accrual_proc_dt > :1
  and  plan_type in ('50', '51')
  and  hrs_taken_unproc = 0
  and  (emplid, plan_type, accrual_proc_dt) 
         not in ( 
                  select emplid, plan_type, accrual_proc_dt
                  from   ps_y_sic_vac_hrs
                  where  accrual_proc_dt > :1
                    and  plan_type in ('50', '51')
                    and  hrs_taken_unproc = 0
                    and  y_no_hrs_taken   = 'Y'

                )
;
```

Comment: It's possible I may have explained incorrectly in my question, but if you change `and  y_no_hrs_taken   = 'N'` to `and  y_no_hrs_taken   = 'Y'` in your subselect in your answer, it gives me the desired results.

Comment: @CacheStaheli - no, you explained it correctly, I just didn't pay close enough attention (and didn't have your data to test the solution). I will edit the post to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

@mathguy's answer almost worked for me, but what I really needed was this:

```
select emplid, empl_rcd, company, plan_type, accrual_proc_dt, hrs_taken_unproc
from   ps_leave_accrual
where  accrual_proc_dt > :1
  and  plan_type in ('50', '51')
  and  hrs_taken_unproc = 0
  and  (emplid, plan_type, accrual_proc_dt) 
         not in ( 
                  select emplid, plan_type, accrual_proc_dt
                  from   ps_y_sic_vac_hrs
                  where  accrual_proc_dt > :1
                    and  plan_type in ('50', '51')
                    and (y_no_hrs_taken = 'Y' 
                        or hrs_taken_unproc <> 0
                    )
                )
;
```

I needed to filter out  two types of rows from the staging table:

1. Where the `hrs_taken_unproc` was `0` *and* they had marked the flag indicating they had reviewed it.
2. The rows that they had "corrected" the hours for (`0` in the original payroll table, but `<> 0` in the staging table).

Comment: If the hours are 0 in the payroll table but >0 in the staging table, do you care if the y_no flag is 'Y' or 'N'? That is a bit odd - what if the hours are 0 in the payroll table, 20 in the staging table, and the flag is 'Y'? Then - either way, you can put all of this together in a single subquery: change the last two lines of the first subquery to `and ( (hrs_taken_unproc = 0 and y_no_hrs_taken = 'Y') or hrs_taken_unproc <> 0 )`  - or add the flag condition at the end if it is really needed.

Comment: That makes sense. They _are_ mutually exclusive. The flag can only be set when the hours are 0. I will change the query.